# How to combine multiple zipcode polygons into one polygon

Tags: polygon, carto, zip-codes

In CartoDB, we have a table of chapters that make up a national organization.  Each chapter record has a polygon that defines the geographical area that the chapter covers.  The area a chapter covers is defined by zipcodes and which zipcodes are included in a chapter can change over time.  I understand that CartoDB has a table with polygon information for US zipcodes.  Given a zipcode to chapter table that I can produce, I'd like to create a fairly simple process to redefine the chapter polygons using the CartoDB zipcode/polygon table. I have the following specific questions.

1. What is the zip/polygon table name and how do I reference it in queries?
2. What's the best way to use my zip to chapter mapping table and the CartoDB zip/polygon table to create a single polygon for each chapter?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please be sure to take the [Tour] where something to note is that asking one question per question leads to clearer Q&As.

Answer (score 1):

There's no zipcodes table publicly accessible. You need to create a table with the zipcodes you need (one per row!) and then geocode this table by using the Postal Codes option, selecting in the second selector 'United States'.

If I understood well, your regions are composed by several zipcodes that you want to group in order to form them, right? You can, in the zipcodes table too, add a column to specify to which region does a zipcode belong.

The way to combine polygons is by using the PostGIS function 'ST_Union' in the SQL tab of the CartoDB Editor. You'd need, at least, a table with the geometries and different values that you want to group (in this case, your regions).

In terms of SQL queries, you'd need to do something like:

> INSERT INTO new_regions_table (the_geom, name) SELECT
>   **ST_Union(the_geom)**, 'region_name' FROM zipcodes_table where name =
>   'region_name'

This will insert in a new regions table the combined geometries and its name.

You could check the PostGIS documentation about ST_Union here: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer i work for https://boundaries-io.com **

the return geoJson will be multiple polygons in a GeoJson Response..this can be easily rendered in GoogleMap,etc.

Very simple solution to this. sign up here: https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/boundaries-io

then in your code  you have a bunch of zipcodes for Richmond,VA: `../rest/v1/public/boundary?zipcode=23235,23236 ...`

Results are this [GeoJson](https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/d9fff0eae64f15b65b956ca83fda2531)
[image: multiple zipcode polygons from query above]

Now If i need to combine all zipcodes to one add a query parmeter:
`../rest/v1/public/boundary?zipcode=23235,23236 ...?combine=true`

Results are this [GeoJson](https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/ce7b902921d964032097fe5330e1ab11) 
[image: Combined multiple zipcodes to one polygon]